# react query optimistic update "old is not iterable" why this error occured

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Updating profile is working fine, but optimistic update is not working properly. An error occured 'old is not iterable'. How to fix this ?

```
  export const useUpdateProfile = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation(updateProfile, {
    onMutate: async (newProfile) => {
      // Cancel any outgoing refetches (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
      await queryClient.cancelQueries("user-profile");
      // Snapshot the previous value
      const previousProfile = queryClient.getQueryData("user-profile");

      // Optimistically update to the new value
      queryClient.setQueryData(["user-profile"], (old) => [...old, newProfile]);

      // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
      return { previousTodos };
    },
    // If the mutation fails, use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
    onError: (err, newTodo, context) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData("user-profile", context.previousProfile);
    },
    // Always refetch after error or success:
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("user-profile");
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the getting the `user-profile` gives you back `undefined`, potentially because it doesn't exist? Make sure to check for `undefined` before spreading:

```
// Optimistically update to the new value
queryClient.setQueryData(["user-profile"], (old) => old ? [...old, newProfile] : []);
```

if you've upgraded to v4 (@tanstack/react-query) already, you can also *return* undefined from the updater to bail out of the update:

```
queryClient.setQueryData(["user-profile"], (old) => old ? [...old, newProfile] : undefined);
```